# Github: How to work across multiple forks of the same repository

Tags: git, github

I'm contributing to a new-ish project on github and two of us would like to collaborate on a reasonably decent sized feature. Normally I think you'd have a branch in the original repo we'd work on but we don't want to pepper the maintainer with PRs. I thought I could work on the other contributors repo and once it's in good shape, send it over.

However I'm also submitting PR's to the main repo as well and I'm not sure how to arrange things to satisfy both requirements in terms of contributing to two differenta usere fork and the original of the same repo.

I know the workflow would be the following and but unsure how to accomplish it

1. Fork the original project to myself i.e. `original/repo.git` -> `myself/repo.git`
2. Clone `myself/repo.git` to local
3. Set an upstream of `otherguy/repo.git` (how?)
4. Checkout branch `new_feature` from otherguy/repo.git (how?)
5. Do some work, send it to my `myself/repo.git` and submit a PR to `otherguy/repo.git` (I think some push extra command line magic required?)

Then the tricky part

1. Switch back to `original/repo.git` and sync with main
2. Do some local work and push to `myself/repo.git` on a different branch
3. Send a PR

Then of course switch back to `otherguy/repo.git`

Is this even possible? Am I making it harder than it has to be?

Comment: "Is this even possible" Absolutely. It's completely up to you how many remotes your repo has, and any branch may be synced up or down with any remote.

Answer (score 2):

Your Idea of the basic workflow looks good.

`git remote add <name> <url>` you can just add the other guys fork

`git remote -v` you can check where every remote points to. By convention `origin` pints to your fork and `upstream` points to the original repo. But those are just names you can pick whatever you want.

`git fetch --all` fetches all repos. At this point you should have a bunch of remote tracking branches. All the branch names start with the remote names you picked `<remote name>/<branch>`

`git checkout -b <new branch> <remote>/<branch>` will just create a new local branch from any of the remote branches, but you can use the remote branches like any other branch (merge, rebase)

`git push <remote> <from>:<to>` you can push anything you like to the remote most likely you only have access to your fork. `<from>` is your local branch name, `<to>` is the branch on the remote.

Then there is just the PR left, there is no magic with git just using the commands you already know. There is no switching between remotes, its all one thing. Just pick the branches you want to work on and push to the remotes you want to ship to.